# How to pull to a bare git repository, whose origin is a github repository?

Tags: git, github

I have made a bare repository (MY_LOCAL_REP) out of a public git repository hosted in github:

```
~$ git clone --bare <github repository location>
```

The github repository had been updated (a branch was created) and I want to fetch the changes to MY_LOCAL_REP, so I ran

```
~$ git fetch
```

The command completes successfully, but when I run

```
~$ git branch
```

I don't see the new branch. What am I doing wrong? what is the correct way to 'pull' from a github repository into a bare repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `git fetch`, it will fetch all of the remote branches, but won't create any new local branches. If you do a `git branch -a`, you should see the new branch - it will be named something along the lines of remotes/origin/branchname

To create a local version of the branch, you can just do `git branch <branchname> origin/<branchname>` - this will create a new local branch that tracks the remote branch.

This assumes that you already have a remote set up named `origin`. See [git branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) and [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) for more info about these commands.

Answer (score 4):

Use `git clone --mirror` instead of `git clone --bare` if you want a bare repository that looks exactly like the remote repository.

See the [git-clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) manpage for more info.